# How do I delete a folder in a branch of TFS, but not in the main part?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

We need to delete a folder in one of our branches, but do not want it deleted in the main/root repository. The deleted folder is gone in ONE older version, but the newer versions retain it, as do the older versions.

I deleted it in the branch, merged to main, then in main did "undo pending changes" on that folder. The problem is each new merge to main, it wants to delete that folder again. How do I tell it to leave it in the main/root?

Comment: Maybe there is another way to accomplish the end result you are looking for.  Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish?  Why do you need to be able to delete the folder in a branch, but suppress the deletion from merging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a changeset from being merged, you need to [**discard**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy) it. This is done from the Command Prompt.

> The following example discards changeset 137 as a candidate for
>   merging into branch2.
>
> ```
> tf merge /discard /version:C137 branch1 branch2 /recursive
> ```

Comment: To do this, I then merge again from 13.0 to main (it will again then set the folder in main to delete) And I then run "tf merge /discard /version:C137 13.0 main /recursive" where C137 is the changeset when I first merged 13.0 -> main where it wanted to delete that folder ????? ps - thank you

Comment: 1. Delete the folder on the branch and Check-in 2. Run the discard for the specific delete changeset (specific version syntax: `/version:C137~C137`) 3. Merge branch to main -> the delete should not occur.

Comment: I already ran the merge branch -> main. Can I run discard anyways and it will sort itself out? Or will that get it confused? There's also 2 check in since I did that merge, can I still roll back that one changeset safely to then do this?

Comment: When you do a merge, it creates pending changes marked with merge action type. If you haven't committed the merge yet, you can undo it, run the discard and the repeat the merge as normal. The pending changes should not include the delete changeset. If you already committed, then you can rollback the merge changeset. The discard will affect the merges done since the it was applied.