# Partial rollback of a TFS branch operation

Tags: version-control, tfs

I branch two files, `alice.txt` and `bob.txt` in TFS. Then another user edits `alice.txt` in the new branch.

How do I rollback the branch operation for just `bob.txt`, without rolling back `alice.txt` as well?

Comment: You need to [dicard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22493456/147211) the changeset of bob.txt if it's done in a separate changeset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  A branch is an atomic operation, you either rollback the entire branch operation or none of it.